# Is there a way to make illustrator tools dynamic like Corel Draw?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, corel-draw

One of reasons I prefer CorelDraw (or any other) over illustrator is that CorelDraw tools are dynamic i.e. when I click on one tools, its more options and features appear in the above tools bar.

For some reasons I want to use illustrator in some cases and I want to know

> **Q:** Is there a way to make illustrator tools dynamic like Corel Draw?

Comment: They do that in illustrator too its just hidden by the default user interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show the Controls bar in the window menu, each tool will have options there.
Some tools have finest controls when you double clic on them (like the transformation) and some (like basics shapes) when you clic on the canvas instead of clic and drag to create the shape.